# Using strpos with haystack as an array (in WordPress)?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to use strpos() with the $haystack converted from an array to a string? My temporary solution was to use in_array() instead, but it is less than ideal:

```
function dynamic_id() {

    $find_str = get_body_class();

    if ( in_array( 'single-sfwd-courses', $find_str ) || in_array( 'single-sfwd-lessons', $find_str ) || in_array( 'single-sfwd-topic', $find_str) || in_array( 'single-sfwd-quiz', $find_str ) ) {
        echo 'id="jumbo_bg1"';
        echo '><style type="text/css">
        .jumbotron a.btn {
            display: none;
        }
        </style';
    } else {
        echo 'id="jumbo_bg"';
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is `$find_str`?  Is that a string or an array?  So, you want to see if `$find_str` contains any of those various strings, right?

Comment: $find_str is an array. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to see if any of those values in in your array.  In that case, I'd try to make an array of values then use `array_intersect()` to see if any of them match.

If `array_intersect()` returns an array with at least one value, that means there was a match.

```
function dynamic_id() {
    $find_str = get_body_class();
    $vals = array('single-sfwd-courses', 'single-sfwd-lessons', 'single-sfwd-topic', 'single-sfwd-quiz');

    $intersect = array_intersect($find_str, $vals);

    if(count($intersect) > 0){
        // There was a match
    }
    else{
        // No match
    }
}
```